# Exception "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError"

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

While submitting a spark  java code in intellij causing Exception

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError"

**Submit command:**

```
spark-submit --master local[*] --class sparkdemo.spark_demo "E:\ExtraSoftwares\spark_demo\target\spark_demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"
```

**POM file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>sparkdemo</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark_demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: So what is your main question?

Comment: could you share your code ?